# USBHIDDRIVER , getting started

Tags: c#, vb.net, usb, hid

newb warning*.   using vb c#, windows7x64, i added USBHIDDRIVER reference, and imported on firstlines:

using USBHIDDRIVER;

i have also tried several examples such as simple HID,  but USBHIDDRIVER example I used here seems more to my level:

```
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            USBHIDDRIVER.USBInterface usbI = new USBInterface("vid_045E", "pid_028E");

 byte[] startCMD = new byte[8];
startCMD[7] = 4;
usbI.Connect();

            usbI.write(startCMD);              //breakpoint goes here

        }
```

i am testing on two seperate HID-game controllers, both can be detected using USBlyzer,

i can play games on first controller no problem:

```
Instance ID:    HID\VID_045E&PID_028E&IG_00\9&1C2DA766&0&0000
Hardware IDs:   HID\VID_045E&PID_028E&IG_00
    HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_GAME
    HID_DEVICE_UP:0001_U:0005
    HID_DEVICE
```

second controller, i am writing this program cos generic driver is able to receive buttons but not advanced controls, which i want to decode for this application specifically ,

```
Instance ID:    HID\VID_054C&PID_03D5&COL01\6&1461C0C1&0&0000
Hardware IDs:   HID\VID_054C&PID_03D5&REV_0300&Col01
    HID\VID_054C&PID_03D5&Col01
    HID_DEVICE_SYSTEM_GAME
    HID_DEVICE_UP:0001_U:0005
    HID_DEVICE
```

but when i hit breakpoint watch says:

```
isConnected false   bool
usbPID  "pid_028E"  string
usbVID  "vid_045E"  string
```

im sure there is something simple im missing as is usually the case!

Answer (score 0):

Try
USBInterface("045E", "028E");
or just
USBInterface("045E");